# Checking for Valid xml - TBXML crashes if invalid xml

Tags: objective-c, xml

Hi there
In my app, everything working fine with handling xml and parsing it.
But since the xml is from a remote source, i would like to add some code that will check if the xml is valid before parsing it; mainly because TBXML crashes the app if the xml is not valid.

How can i check if the xml is valid ? I tried to use "try" and "catch" but the error is not being caught; this is how my code is

```
TBXMLElement * root ;   
@try {
root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
}
@catch (NSException * e) {      
NSLog(@"error");
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, EXC_BAD_ACCESS inside TBXML. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether there is a valid root element. Someithing like this:

```
if ([[TBXML elementName:parser.rootXMLElement] isEqualToString:@"fooBar"])
...
```

Comment: Is `TBXML` really upper case? It seems that the OP uses a lower-case `tbxml` variable or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It should be. In my example, `elementName:` is a static method called from class `TBXML`. `tbxml` in OP's code is an instance variable IMHO.

Comment: Hi there guys, thanks for your response, but after 2 years? :)
Cant remember how i solved this or used a different approach, but honestly i cannot remember.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using an if statement whether it is nil or not. See the below example.

```
TBXMLElement * rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

    if (rootXMLElement != nil)

        NSLog(@"ok");
        else 
        NSLog(@"Can't proceed: XMLElement is nil");
```

Comment: i already have that, i am trying to catch a situation where the server return  a 404 error page instead of xml